# Enable debug output for optimization passes from clang

Tags: debugging, llvm, clang

I am trying to understand an existing pass in LLVM and thus trying to print the nicely written debug messages in the pass. I am doing so by using `clang -debug -some-other-flags`. However while compiling it says:

`clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-debug'`

How to enable the debug output?

Comment: Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Clang does not have a "debug" command-line option; you need to either build the IR from clang and then run `opt -debug` separately, or run `clang -mllvm -debug`.

In general, the `-mllvm` flag passes whatever appears afterwards on to LLVM itself. Use multiple `-mllvm` flags if you want to pass multiple options onwards.

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks. May I ask what is the role of `-mllvm` flag ?

Comment: @mishr It passes whatever appears afterwards on to LLVM itself.

Comment: If you run passes using Clang, there are likely many of them. In this case, something like `-mllvm -debug-only=simplifycfg` might be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

In case the accepted answer does not work for you: apart from adding `-mllvm -debug`, you [need clang which is built with debug assertions enabled](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/llvm-dev/XbhHxfmNYLY), which is done by adding `-DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=On` to cmake options when compiling clang ([ref](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary)).